# Von Dyck groups that are conjugated.

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

Let us consider the Von Dyck groups 
$$
D(a,b,c)=\langle x,y,z\mid  x^{a}=y^{b}=z^{c}=xyz=1\rangle
$$
 and 
$$
D(a'.b',c')=\langle x,y,z\mid x^{a'}=y^{b'}=z^{c'}=xyz=1\rangle.
$$
Suppose
$$
\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}<1,\quad \frac{1}{a'}+\frac{1}{b'}+\frac{1}{c'}<1.
$$
I have read that in this case
$$
\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}= \frac{1}{a'}+\frac{1}{b'}+\frac{1}{c'}
$$
implies that $D(a,b,c)$ and $D(a',b',c')$ are conjugated. How could we prove it?

Comment: What do you mean by conjugated?

Comment: @DerekHolt If I am not wrong, the Von Dyck group $D(a,b,c)$ with $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}<1$ can be understand as a subgroup of $\mathbb{P}\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$. Accordingly, $D(a,b,c)$ and $D(a',b',c')$ are conjugated if there exists $g\in \mathbb{P}\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ such that $gD(a,b,c)g^{-1}=D(a',b',c')$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can be correct. $D(3,6,8)$ has abelianization $C_6$, whereas $D(4,4,8)$ has abelianization $C_4^2$, so the groups are not isomorphic.